# Как проверить какая зависимость имеет дубликат?

Tags: java, android

Проект компилируется нормально и загружается на телефон

Проблема появляется тогда когда я хочу сделать дебаг АПК файл

Получаю вот такую ошибку

```
Cause: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzxk.class
```

Не знаю с чего начать

Comment: Clean Project делали?

Comment: Чето с Play services. выкладывайте зависимости, весь build.gradle. gradle dependencies может помочь

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes